# Word wrapping in a span in IE8

Tags: css, word-wrap, html

I am attempting to get word wrapping to work in a span.  Currently I am using "word-wrap:break-word;" which works in most browsers, however there is a requirement for word wrapping to work in IE8.
Are there any other methods of doing this which will support more browsers?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `word-wrap: break-word` is broken in IE when using on an inline element, even if its enclosing block defines a width. Finally figured out that it works on blocks. If you want to make it work on a span you must set the `display` property to `inline-block` or replace the `span` with a `div` or a `p`.

Comment: Changing the `span` to a `div` works great for me, but unfortunately adding `display:inline-block` makes the text not wrap again.